# MapView not displaying Route

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I have already checked that coordinates are available, but when I launch the map snaps to Antartica, and the route is not drawn when I go to the place in the map it should be.

I am attempting to do this programatically so maybe there is something I missed, if you spot it please let me know. There is no additional code

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    
    var locationManager : CLLocationManager?
    var routeData : Route?
    var routeCoordinates : [CLLocation] = []
    var routeOverlay: MKOverlay?
    
    let mapView : MKMapView = {
        let map = MKMapView()
        map.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
        map.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return map
    }()
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        setMapConstraints()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let routeJSON = self.getJSON() {
            self.parseJSON(jsonData: routeJSON)
        }
        
        drawRoute(routeData: routeCoordinates)
        
        print(routeCoordinates)
    }
    
    private func setMapConstraints() {
        view.addSubview(mapView)
        
        mapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        mapView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        mapView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
    }
    
    //Omitted - functions for parsing local JSON file - tested and is working fine
    
    //Function that handles drawing of route on map
    func drawRoute(routeData: [CLLocation]) {
        if routeCoordinates.count == 0 {
            return
        }
        
        let coordinates = routeCoordinates.map { (location) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in
            return location.coordinate
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.routeOverlay = MKPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
            self.mapView.addOverlay(self.routeOverlay!, level: .aboveRoads)
            let customEdgePadding: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 40, left: 20, bottom: 40, right: 20)
            self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(self.routeOverlay!.boundingMapRect, edgePadding: customEdgePadding, animated: false)
        }
    }

}

extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = .systemIndigo
        renderer.lineCap = .round
        renderer.lineWidth = 3.0

        return renderer
    }

}
```

Comment: Where does a guy named 'routeData' come from?

Comment: routeData is just a local json file that stores longitude and latitude coordinates

Comment: How are you going to make a route or routes without `MKDirections`?

Comment: Is it not possible to draw a route from the first coordinate to the next coordinate up until the last coordinate using the array of coordinates? Or is my logic here off?

Comment: I see.  So you are not making a route but connecting dots to draw a series of `MKPolyline`.  I don't see mapView.delegate = self in your code.

Comment: Of course it was going to be something so simple...thank you.